# Password used during installation of Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: password, 15.10

I'm setting up this box for a friend, and entered a simple password during installation.
I set it to auto login, so it does come up to the desktop.

All setup and ready to reset the password to one of their choosing, and the password I used is rejected.  Quite sure I am entering it correctly, caps off, etc.  Tried both the gui and sudo password.

Since this is a fresh install, does it just make sense to reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a fresh install you should try reinstalling it.

> Don't get stuck in just one thing,you have to explore a lot of things in Ubuntu.

So if you have tried everything and you think that you are using the right passsord then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is what I ended up doing.  So easy to install these days anyway.

Comment: yeah all OK.. and if you liked the answer you can accept it by clicking the tick mark in left of the answer. :-)

Comment: I did, but it does not seem to register.